# When is $(A + A^\top)$ PSD even though A is not PSD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

I am wondering if there are any constraints which can be places on a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to ensure that $A + A^\top$ is positive semidefinite (PSD) even though $A$ itself is not PSD.

It is easy to see that if $A$ is PSD, then...

$$
x^\top (A + A^\top)x =  x^\top A x + x^\top A^\top x = 2 x^\top Ax \geq 0
$$

Can it ever be the case that $A$ is not PSD but $A + A^\top$ is? What would need to be satisfied?

EDIT:

I assume $A$ is not symmetric or triangular.

Comment: What is a "PSD"?

Comment: PSD = positive semidefinite

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it would probably be better to write it out in full.

Comment: The assumption that $A$ is not triangular is somewhat artificial, and can be skirted easily. If you add an anti-symmetric matrix to a triangular matrix, you'll get another matrix whose sum with its transpose will produce the same result.

Comment: @TheoBendit interesting. Can any square matrix be expressed as an antisymmetric matrix + a triangular matrix? Intuitively it seems so, but I am not sure. I suppose then that is is only required that the triangular matrix have an all positive diagonal in order to be PSD?

If the above is true, then really it only requires that A have an all positive diagonal? Maybe..

Comment: @Joff According to the usual definition of "positive semidefinite" (to the extent that this definition is at all applied to non-symmetric matrices), your sequence of equalities show that $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $A + A^\top$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x^T (A+A^T)x \geq 0$ and $x^TAx < 0$ (i.e. not positive semi-definite). We know that any matrix can be decomposed into symmetric and antisymmetric matrices that is $A=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)+\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$ and $x^T A^T x=x^TAx$ (i.e. scalars are symmetric). We have
$$
x^T A x < 0 \implies \frac{1}{2} x^T(A+A^T)x < 0
$$

If $A$ negative definite, so is $(A+A^T)$ but this contradicts our assumption that $A+A^T$ is positive semi definite, therefore, $A$ must be positive semi definite.

Comment: The assumption that $A$ is not PSD is meant to imply that $x^\top A x \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ does not hold. Stating that $x^\top A x \lt 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a quite a stronger statement. For instance, if $x^\top A x$ has some negative eigenvalues then it is not PSD, but also not ND.

Comment: @Joff, If $A$ is not PSD, then it must be either PS, ND, NSD, or indefinite. These are the only possible cases. You will get the same conclusion if you apply my answer to all cases. It was just a brief look at one case.

Comment: What is meant by PS in your comment?

Comment: @Joff, sorry, I meant PD.

Comment: It took me a while to think about it, but I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $A + A^\top = B + B^\top$, then $A - B = -(A - B)^\top$. That is, the difference between the two matrices is an anti-symmetric matrix $M$, i.e. satisfying $M = -M^\top$. And, adding any such matrix $M$ to $A$ will make
$$(A + M) + (A + M)^\top = A + M + A^\top + M^\top = A + A^\top - M^\top + M^\top =  A + A^\top.$$
That is, once we find a particular solution to $A + A^\top = P$, where $P$ is a fixed PSD matrix, then the remaining solutions will differ by an anti-symmetric matrix $M$. Taking the easy solution $A = P/2$, we see the solutions are:
$$\left\{\frac{P}{2} + M : M = -M^\top\right\}.$$
All this should make sense if you've studied linear equations. The map $A \mapsto A + A^\top$ is linear, making $A + A^\top = P$ a non-homogeneous linear equation. The solution is formed by taking a particular solution $P/2$ and adding the nullspace of the linear map, which are all these $M$ matrices.

Also, we could take the particular solution to be a triangular matrix, which affirmatively answers your question in the comments. However, if we take the particular solution to be $P/2$, we have the advantage that we only require $M \neq 0$, and we will definitely get a non-symmetric (and hence not PSD) matrix! This is because,
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{P}{2} + M\right)^\top = \frac{P}{2} + M &\iff \frac{P^\top}{2} + M^\top = \frac{P}{2} + M \\
&\iff \frac{P}{2} + M^\top = \frac{P}{2} + M \\
&\iff M^\top = M \\
&\iff M^\top = -M^\top \\
&\iff 2M^\top = 0 \\
&\iff M = 0.
\end{align}